# Filter DataFrame rows by multiple columns and add them together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

So I have a dataframe structured like:

```
Date        Metric  Value
2020-01-01  Low     34.5
2020-01-01  High    36.5
2020-01-01  Open    23.5
2020-01-02  Low     32.5
...
```

I am trying to create another frame, where for every date there is a new 'Volume' column which is the High-low for that specific date. The frame is not keyed on the dates so it needs to be joined and then values in different columns added together? Not sure exactly how to do this. I'm trying to get the final result to look like this:

```
Date        Volume
2020-01-01  2.00
2020-01-02  6.45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows:

- First, select only from `df` the rows which have `High` and `Low` in column `Metric` using [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).
- Next, use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape the `df` and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) a new column `Volume`, containing the result of values in column `Low` subtracted from those in column `High` (see: [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)).
- Finally, we add some cosmetic changes: we [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) columns `High` and `Low`, reset the index (see: [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)), and get rid of `df.columns.name` (which is automatically set to `Metric` during `df.pivot`).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Date': {0: '2020-01-01', 1: '2020-01-01', 2: '2020-01-01', 
                 3: '2020-01-02', 4: '2020-01-02', 5: '2020-01-02'}, 
        'Metric': {0: 'Low', 1: 'High', 2: 'Open', 3: 'Low', 4: 'High', 
                   5: 'Open'}, 
        'Value': {0: 34.5, 1: 36.5, 2: 23.5, 3: 32.5, 4: 38.95, 5: 32.5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

res = df[df.Metric.isin(['Low','High'])].pivot(index='Date', columns='Metric', 
                                               values='Value')

res = res.assign(Volume=res['High'].sub(res.Low)).drop(
    ['High', 'Low'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=False)
res.columns.name = None

print(res)

         Date  Volume
0  2020-01-01    2.00
1  2020-01-02    6.45
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 dataframes by filtering by low & high and join them by date. Finally, subtract columns low from high.

```py
data=[
    ("2020-01-01","Low",34.5),
    ("2020-01-01","High",36.5),
    ("2020-01-01","Open",23.5),
    ("2020-01-02","Low",32.5),
    ("2020-01-02","High",38.95),
]

columns = ["Date", "Metric", "Value"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df_low = df[df["Metric"]=="Low"].rename(columns={"Value": "Low"}).drop("Metric", axis=1)
df_high = df[df["Metric"]=="High"].rename(columns={"Value": "High"}).drop("Metric", axis=1)
df2 = df_low.merge(df_high, on="Date", how="inner")
df2["Volume"] = df2["High"] - df2["Low"]

[Out]:
         Date   Low   High  Volume
0  2020-01-01  34.5  36.50    2.00
1  2020-01-02  32.5  38.95    6.45
```